# kivy sounds doesn't work on win 8

Tags: python, linux, windows, kivy

I've tested my code on ubuntu and it work properly but when i test it on windows8, the sound doesn't played.

I coded a new app but it doesn't work too. does windows have special setting?
why i can't play sound?

it will be a mobile app but not compeleted yet.
were is the problem?
does it work on mobile?

here is my code:

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
#from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader



Builder.load_string('''
<MenuPage>:
    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint:(.1, None)
            Button:
                text: 'Credit'
                on_press:root.show_popup()
        ListView:
            size_hint: .8, .97
            item_strings: [str(index) for index in range(40)]
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint:(.1, None)
            Button:
                text: 'atlas'
                on_press:root.plays()


<Page>:
    BoxLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint:(.1, None)
            Button:
                text: 'MENU'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            Button:
                text:root.name
                size_hint:(1, .2)
            Image:
                source: '/home/hosein/Pictures/1.png'
                size_hint:(1, .8)
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint:(.1, None)

            Button:
                text: 'atlas'
<Credit>:
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: 'CREDIT'
    size_hint:.6, .6
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        Label:
            text:'Coded By hosein Ramezan'
        Button:
            text: 'close'
            size_hint:1, .2
            on_press: root.dismiss()
''')


class Credit(Popup):
    pass


class MenuPage(Screen):
    M = SoundLoader.load('/home/hosein/Music/Man.mp3')
    M.play()

    def plays(self):
        if MenuPage.M.state == 'stop':
            MenuPage.M.play()
        else:
            MenuPage.M.stop()

    def show_popup(self):
        P = Credit()
        P.open()


class Page(Screen):
    pass



sm = ScreenManager()
menu = MenuPage(name='menu')
sm.add_widget(menu)
for i in range(4):
    name = Page(name=str(i))
    sm.add_widget(name)


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: it was difference between version 1.8 and 1.9 in kivy.

Comment: mp3 format does not supported, in 1.8 kivy handle the error but in 1.9 not !